# Vagrant wait for other box to finish booting

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm in the process of learning how to set up Puppet ( master and agents ). I'd like to have Vagrant start up several boxes; one as the Puppet master, the rest as agents that'd use that box to get their configurations from.

Is there a way to tell Vagrant to ensure that one box is loaded before attempting to bring up others?

For example, if I've got three boxes, defined like so:

```rb
  config.vm.define "master" do |test|
    test.vm.box = "puppetlabs/ubuntu-12.04-64-puppet"
    test.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
    test.vm.hostname = "puppet-master"
    test.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end

  config.vm.define "web01" do |web01|
    web01.vm.box = "puppetlabs/ubuntu-12.04-64-puppet"
    web01.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.01"
    web01.vm.hostname = "web01-dev"
    web01.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end

  config.vm.define "web02" do |web02|
    web02.vm.box = "puppetlabs/ubuntu-12.04-64-puppet"
    web02.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.02"
    web02.vm.hostname = "web02-dev"
    web02.ssh.forward_agent = true
  end
```

Is there a way to have `web01` and `web02` make sure that `puppet-master` is up and running before booting? Or do I just have to manually make sure that the boxes boot in the right order? I'd prefer to have some sort of configuration option, so that I don't have to rely on other people on my team reading docs before running `vagrant up`.